# Split list of dict to list of keys, list of values

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, key

Consider the following `list` of `dict`.

```
food = [{'pizza': 324}, {'sandwich': 78}, {'hot dog': 90}]
```

How can I separate out into `lists` the keys and values as so;

```
[pizza, sandwich, hot dog]
[324,78,90]
```

Comment: Why do you have a list of dictionaries? A dictionary is already a collection of items, so surely it would be easier if you would have that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
keys = food.keys()
values = food.values()
```

**edit:**

I realized that splitting a dictionary this way would not maintain the order between keys and values because a dictionary is not ordered.

So keys[0] may not represent the price of values[0]. If you want to keep the order between the 2 lists consistent then you will have to do this

```
for key,values in food.items():
    keylist.append(key)
    valuelist.append(values)
```

**edit2:**
Although the above methods will retrieve the keys and values from a dictionary. You have your data stored across multiple list items where each item is a dictionary.

As @cristian has already pointed out this is unnecessary as a dictionary can hold multiple items.

You are better of storing it as
food = {"pizza":324, "sandwich": 78, "hot dog" :90}

But in any case, you can retrieve your data as

```
keys = []
values = []
for item in food:
    keys.append(item.keys())
    values.append(item.values())
```

which can be simplified to

```
keys = [*(x.keys() for d in food)]
values = [*(x.values() for x in food)]
```

Comment: food has no items

Comment: could you be a bit more specific? Is that an error you're getting?

Comment: @Vendant Shetty yes, that is the error I am getting. Sorry my comment was confusing

Comment: I see what happened there. You have a list of dictionary items. As Cristian already pointed out, this is kinda unnecessary but in any case, I'll update the answer to work on a list of dictionary items

Comment: @Vedanet Shetty , alright thanks. I especially like your second answer, it's more of what I was looking for.